# Cucumber Textmate Highlighting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, textmate

I am trying to get highlighting for Cucumber to work with Textmate.
I already installed the [Cucumber Textmate Bundle](http://github.com/bmabey/cucumber-tmbundle) (which is supposed to include the highlighting).
I am working with Ryan Bates' [Railscasts theme](http://media.railscasts.com/resources/textmate_theme.zip) (description for it is in the [about page](http://railscasts.com/about)) for textmate, but for some reason `In order to`, `As a`, `I want`, etc do not get highlighted in `foobar.feature` located in my features folder.

Seems like it's working for for Ryan in his "[Beginning with Cucumber](http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber)" screencast.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle adds some new keywords that aren't shipped with the standard TM fonts for highlighting.  You actually need to install one of the themes that ships with the bundle. 
Per the [README](http://github.com/bmabey/cucumber-tmbundle/blob/master/README.textile) install instructions: "To install the color themes for the syntax highlighting: Click on the themes found in the color_themes dir by clicking on them in Finder."

If you want to use the bundle with your current theme you will need to add the keywords and choose appropriate colors for your theme.  You can see examples of this by installing one of the ones that ships with the bundle and then going into "Preferences -> Fonts & Colors".

If you do end up adjusting another theme to work with the bundle please let me know so I can incorporate it into the bundle. :)

However, after rereading your question.. Are you just wondering about why the feature's narrative is not highlighted?  (The narrative is the "In order to..." text.)  If so, the highlighting of that was purposely removed.  Aslak thought it shouldn't be highlighted, and I agreed with him, because the narrative should really be custom and whatever works for you.  It also was annoying to have those highlighted since it would sometimes highlight the scenario sections incorrectly as well.

Comment: Thank you! For now, the words `Feature`, `I`, `Scenario`, `Given`, `When` etc.. actually DO get highlighted. It's the documentation words (`In order`, `As a(n)`, `I want`) that do not get highlighted. I'm not sure whether Ryan updated his bundle on his own computer and didn't update it online or if there's something funky going on with my computer. Will post an update soon.

Comment: Aha! Saw your 'However' paragraph. Marking as answered.
Thank you very much for writing this amazing bundle! I love the table-cell auto-alignment feature. I appreciate you taking the time to write this answer.

Comment: Like Ben said - the bundle _used_ to hihglight "In Order", "As a", "I want", but it doesn't any more.

It doesn't anymore because I don't want to prescribe the usage of these terms. Cucumber does not prescribe it and neither should TextMate.

The screencast you saw was probably made before we removed highlighting for those narrative words.

Answer (score 1):

Just so the community knows, the cucumber-tmbundle is now being maintained by the cucumber account on github. The language for the features is Gherkin. And there are new shortcuts to handle different tasks.